# How to connect nodes in a relation to another node that you create at the same time

Tags: graphql, prisma

Consider the structure below

```
mutation createBusiness {
  createBusiness(
    data: {
      ...
      staff: { create: [{ name: "Petros", email: "example@gmail.com" }] }
      services: {
        create: [
          {
            name: "Hair Wash"
            duration: 20
            staff: { ... }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ) {
    id
  }
}
```

So basically a **business** offers **services** and has **staff**. However, the services are run by specific staff members or all of them. So the problem is that at the point of creating the business, the staff members are created and the services need to be created as well.

However I am struggling to connect the **services staff** members to the staff created at the same time.

Any ideas if at all possible?

Comment: this question is tagged with Graphcool but this mutation doesn't quite look like a standard graphcool mutation - so is that tag correct?

Comment: @JonathanIrwin  you are right fixed